# How to use jxls to read floating numbers

Tags: java, excel, jxl, jxls

I cannot read numbers that are less than 0.001, using JXL jar.
When I rear 0.000415 from

`cell.getContents()`

it gives me 0.0 as the result.

When I try to read it from

```
( (NumberRecord) cell ).getValue()
```

it gives me class cast exception.
Can someone please tell me how to read floating numbers from JXL jar.

Answer (score 0):

here `getValue()` return value as `double`.

so you just assign value some variable and check you need not to convert to `NumberRecord`.

and if you require to cast it to `NumberRecord` then check your `NumberRecord` is not type of 
`double`. that is why you get class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after using this

```
if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER)
{
NumberCell nc = (NumberCell) cell;
myDoubleValue = nc.getValue();
}
```